# Saving a Matlab file into a Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matlab

My aim is to extract the values of a Matlab file (called data_123) and store it into a Pandas Dataframe. In particular, the Matlab file contains the variable `roi_mag` which should be stored in the `mag` column of the `data_mag` dataframe.
Then, the `roi` column of the `data_mag` dataframe should contain the position of this `roi_mag` value, but beginning with 1 (so the first `roi_mag` element should have `roi=1`, the second `roi=2` and so on).

I use the following code, but it returns an empty dataframe - why is that?

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import scipy.io

#Create a dataframe
col_names =  ['roi','mag']
data_mag = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)

#Read in Matlab file
path_mag = os.path.join('..', 'data', 'data_123.mat')
mat = scipy.io.loadmat(path_mag)

#Save Matlab variable into dataframe
for roin, mag in enumerate(mat['roi_mag'][0]):
       data_mag.roi = roin + 1
       data_mag.loc[data_mag['roi'] == roin + 1, 'mag'] = mag
```

Edit: I fixed it as follows:

```
for roin, mag in enumerate(mat['roi_mag'][0]):
       data_mag.loc[roin,'roi'] = roin + 1
       data_mag.loc[data_mag['roi'] == roin + 1, 'mag'] = mag
```

Comment: Since data_mag is initially empty, the `data_mag['roi'] == roin + 1` mask doesn't match any rows. You need to fill in the 'roi' column values first.

Comment: Thanks. Why does including "data_mag.roi = roin + 1" into the for loop not work?